# Upper bound of special Cheeger constant on $(S^2,g)$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, systolic-geometry

$(S^2,g)$ is 2-dimensional sphere with Riemannian metric.The Cheeger constant of $(S^2,g)$ is
$$
h(S^2,g)=\inf_{\gamma} \frac{|\gamma|_g}{\min\{|A_1|_g, |A_2|_g\}}
$$
take the infimum over all closed curves $\gamma$  dividing $S^2$ into two parts $A_1,A_2$.  And $|\gamma|_g$ is the length of $\gamma$, $|A_1|_g$ is the area of $A_1$. I spend  several months try to show that
$$
h(S^2,g) \le  2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{|S^2|_g}}. 
$$
However, I fail, and bad mood. But, I transform the above estimate into prove the following conjecture.

**Conjecture:**  For any $(S^2,g)$, the closed curve $\gamma$ is Cheeger set, namely
$$
h(S^2,g)=  \frac{|\gamma|_g}{\min\{|A_1|_g, |A_2|_g\}}.
$$
Besides, $\gamma$ divid $S^2$ into two parts with equal area, namely  $|A_1|_g= |A_2|_g$. Then,
$$
h(S^2,g) \le  2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{|S^2|_g}} 
$$

I still fail to prove it. I have some guess. For example, The special Cheeger set should be the isoperimetric ratio set, namely, $\gamma$ attains
$$
\inf_{\gamma} \frac{|\gamma|_g^2}{\min\{|A_1|_g, |A_2|_g\}}.
$$
If so, I can prove the above conjecture. But, ridiculously, only that the isoperimetric set with $|A_1|_g= |A_2|_g$ is the Cheeger set, I can prove. Maybe, this is the irony of fate.

I really want to end this problem, since  it annoys me for months. If you have  idea, we can work together. My E-mail: 1577728521@qq.com.  Thanks.

**PS(2024-1-13):** After some time, I tried to deal with this conjecture by variations, but it still didn't work. If you think any of the methods or papers  might work,  please let me know. Thank you.